# Typing `unity` in terminal crashes current session

Tags: command-line, unity

If I type `unity` in terminal the session crashes and I'm logged out.

How do I control this? I want to prevent crashing if I type `unity` in terminal by mistake. *(It's because I'm currently using Unity3D so I get confused sometimes)* Or maybe I want to get a warning message.

Comment: An alias which sets `unity` to `unity3d` (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: that's one nice solution! @BharadwajRaju

Comment: Posting as an answer, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it crashes is because that command will try to start a new `unity` session but you're already running one. An easy workaround would be to add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
unity(){
    read -p "Launch a new unity session? [y/n] " re
    if [ $re = "y" ]; then /usr/bin/unity; fi
}
```

Now, when you run `unity` you will be asked whether you actually want to launch a new `unity` session and, unless you answer `y`, nothing will happen. Alternatively, you can choose whether to run `unity` or `unity3D`:

```sh
unity(){
    read -p "Launch a new unity session? [y/n] " re
    if [ $re = "y" ]; then  
        /usr/bin/unity; 
    else
        unity3d
    fi
}
```

Comment: isn't ubuntu just awesome!?  a few simple lines of code can make whatever dreams you have come true! the beauty of open-source LOL XD

Comment: @MinaMichael strictly speaking, there's absolutely nothing related with Ubuntu here. This is a pure bash solution which, apart from the `-p` option of `read` would work with pretty much any POSIX shell and most *nix operating systems.

Comment: I see. okay well that's just me learning! XD thanks! @terdon

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `alias`:

Assuming `unity3d` is the Unity3D executable

```
alias unity='unity3d'
```

in your `~/.bashrc` (or in case of ZSH, `~/.zshrc`)

In case you ever need to run actual `unity` (not `unity3d`), run

```
\unity
```

The command, with a backslash in front, or

```
command unity
```